# Can't forward images to webp with Nginx using Laravel

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I'm trying to forward all jpeg and png images to webp. It's a Laravel project. Most of images in /storage folder as a symlink in public folder. I followed guides and I know a bit regex but I couldn't find any clue what's wrong.

I have webp images in every folder.

```
path/to/image.jpg
path/to/image.jpg.webp
```

ngnix.conf file:

```
sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;

keepalive_timeout  65;

map $http_accept $webp_suffix {
    default "";
    "~*webp" ".webp";
}
```

Server config:

```
server{
    root /var/www/site/public;
    server_name example.com www.example.org;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|webp|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
        expires 365d;
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(png|jpe?g)$ {
        add_header Vary Accept;
        try_files $uri$webp_suffix $uri =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    if ($host = example.org) {
        return 301 https://www.example.org$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot 

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }

    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
   
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server{
    if ($host = www.example.org) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.org) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name example.org www.example.org;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Any help will be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expression `location` blocks are evaluated in order until a match is found. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

You have two `location` expressions which match `.png`, `.jpg` and `.jpeg`. You need to remove these from the first expression for the second expression to succeed.

For example:

```
location ~* \.(gif|ico|css|js)$ {
    expires 365d;
}

location ~* \.(png|jpe?g)$ {
    expires 365d;
    add_header Vary Accept;
    try_files $uri$webp_suffix $uri =404;
}
```

Comment: Yes I just realized that after I post this question. Thanks for the help.